# How do I insert a blank value when field does not exist in Access?

Tags: sql, vba, csv, ms-access, import

I am using vba code in Microsoft Access to import several csv files at once, unfortunately, not all the csv files have the same formatting; some files just have [SKU-1], but some of the files have a second field [SKU-2].

My code works as written below for the files that have both sku-1 and sku-2 as fields in the csv file, however, if a file ONLY has [SKU-1], the import fails with "Too few parameters. Expected 1."

Is there any way to use some sort of case statement to drop a NULL value for SKU-2 if the field itself does not exist to be pulled from?

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO MumbyCSV (OrderID, Email, FirstName, LastName, Company, Phone, SecondaryPhone," & _
        "Fax, ApproveStatus, OrderDate, [SKU-1], [SKU-2], Total, ShiptoName, ShipToAddress1, ShipToAddress2," & _
        "ShipToCity, ShipToState, ShipToZip, ShipToCountry, ShippingMethod, Comments)" & _
        "SELECT OrderID, Email, FirstName, LastName, Company, Phone, SecondaryPhone," & _
        "Fax, ApproveStatus, OrderDate, [SKU-1], [SKU-2], Total, ShiptoName, ShipToAddress1, ShipToAddress2," & _
        "ShipToCity, ShipToState, ShipToZip, ShipToCountry, ShippingMethod, Comments " & _
        "FROM [Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=YES;DATABASE=C:\ImportPath].[test.csv]"
```

Comment: Run a select on the CSV file before doing the insert, then adjust your SQL statement to match the actual file.

Answer (score 0):

Start by checking the number of fields in the file:

```
dim fso : Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
dim file : Set file = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\ImportPath\test.csv")
firstLine = file.ReadLine ' read first line
fieldArray = Split(firstLine, "whateverfielddelimiteryouhave")
numFields = UBound(fieldArray) + 1  'index on arrays from zero
```

This will tell you how many fields there are.  If you have defined both SQL with and without `[SKU-2]` then you can use a simple `IF` to select which to execute:

```
If numFields = 22 Then
sql = "INSERT INTO MumbyCSV (OrderID, Email, FirstName, LastName, Company, Phone, SecondaryPhone," & _
        "Fax, ApproveStatus, OrderDate, [SKU-1], [SKU-2], Total, ShiptoName, ShipToAddress1, ShipToAddress2," & _
        "ShipToCity, ShipToState, ShipToZip, ShipToCountry, ShippingMethod, Comments)" & _
        "SELECT OrderID, Email, FirstName, LastName, Company, Phone, SecondaryPhone," & _
        "Fax, ApproveStatus, OrderDate, [SKU-1], [SKU-2], Total, ShiptoName, ShipToAddress1, ShipToAddress2," & _
        "ShipToCity, ShipToState, ShipToZip, ShipToCountry, ShippingMethod, Comments " & _
        "FROM [Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=YES;DATABASE=C:\ImportPath].[test.csv]" 
Else
sql = "INSERT INTO MumbyCSV (OrderID, Email, FirstName, LastName, Company, Phone, SecondaryPhone," & _
        "Fax, ApproveStatus, OrderDate, [SKU-1], Total, ShiptoName, ShipToAddress1, ShipToAddress2," & _
        "ShipToCity, ShipToState, ShipToZip, ShipToCountry, ShippingMethod, Comments)" & _
        "SELECT OrderID, Email, FirstName, LastName, Company, Phone, SecondaryPhone," & _
        "Fax, ApproveStatus, OrderDate, [SKU-1], Total, ShiptoName, ShipToAddress1, ShipToAddress2," & _
        "ShipToCity, ShipToState, ShipToZip, ShipToCountry, ShippingMethod, Comments " & _
        "FROM [Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=YES;DATABASE=C:\ImportPath].[test.csv]"
End If

CurrentDB.Execute sql
```

A second option would be to read the values to be imported into an array, and where the value is an empty string, replace it with a NULL so that the field doesn't get set on the INSERT step. However if you must import directly from the file as per your code I don't think you can do this.

Comment: This is a good workaround, it is case by case, but I should only have 2-3 different formats that would have different numbers of columns.In the first part of your code, the numfields string seems to end up being the number of commas in the entire file instead of just the first line. How can I fix this?

Comment: I figured it out. My csvs have carriage returns CR instead of line ends CRLF. It's always something.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [TransferText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835958.aspx) which does not require any order of columns and ignores missing columns, just as long as the current file being imported maintains columns somewhere in the table:

```
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , "MumbyCSV", "C:\ImportPath\test.csv", True
```

Comment: I was originally using this method, but it gives a lot of Import error tables  until an import specification file is set. However the second I define an import specification, it breaks if I try to import a csv with different fields than my specification file (which is my problem in the first place; differently formatted csv files flowing in)

Comment: Hmmm...the import spec is optional and does tailor specifically to a structured file. But if your file is clearly comma-separated with column headers and data types aligning to destination table this should work.

Comment: Thanks I did end up using your suggestion using several different spec files and also Dave's suggestion combined to get a fairly robust import now.